# How can I read a CSV file on Box in Stata

Tags: oauth-2.0, stata

R has a library, boxr. that handles the OAuth 2.0 dance and can easily read CSV data stored on box.  Does stata have similar functionality to perform the OAuth dance an use a CSV file?

Comment: Can you give a URL for a toy example?

Comment: https://app.box.com/file/794776954451. The only problem is that I need to give you permission to the file.  If you have a box acct, I'm happy to make you a viewer of the data.  The file is actually public crime data from Montgomery County Maryland. But my use case requires tighter governance of the data.

Comment: I believe there is a way to share the file so that you don't need a box account: https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043697094-Creating-Shared-Links. But it sounds like that does not work for you for some reason. You may have have to use boxr from Stata using rsource or some sort of CLI tool.

Comment: The other option is probably [Box Drive](https://www.box.com/drive?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=SEM&utm_campaign=dm-google-sem-na-eng-brand&utm_keyword=box%20drive&id=7010e000001PaCyAAK&utm_content=454965422821|kwd-304176901196|c&gclid=Cj0KCQjw6-SDBhCMARIsAGbI7Ujg09NXTllgh9Hf8qBjkK6w-i3TthybU_XZG31Tf6u-qBh2pfpxaAQaAnUjEALw_wcB).

Comment: Stata can call R functions? If so, that is a great solution.

Comment: Stata can work with Python, R, Java, and H20.